# Meu arquivo do deploy está com uma versão desatualizada em relação ao meu último commit

Tags: git, deploy, commit, branch

Problema:

Criei um hook (evento) no git que quando efetuo o push para meu repositório local ele deveria criar em uma pasta que no caso chamei de web, um deploy com a cópia do meu arquivo originário da minha branch main porém o grande problema é que ele está sim efetuando o push porém com uma versão completamente desatualizada em relação ao meus últimos commits nessa mesma branch main.

Situação para ajudar no entendimento:

meu arquivo é um html, a situação é que meu arquivo na main está show porém o arquivo gerado a partir do hook que criei está aparentemente com uma versão super antiga de um commit que não é o atual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conhecer o sha-1 do commit que você está enviando permite que você use vários comandos para extrair os arquivos que deseja implantar.

Por exemplo, ao usar o hook `post-receive`, seu script ou binário recebe 3 argumentos, incluindo o sha-1 do commit empurrado (o terceiro).

No hook, pode extrair os arquivos que você deseja, por exemplo com o Bash (provavelmente a ser ajustado):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

commit_sha1="$3"
git archive --format=tar ${commit_sha1} 'caminho/dentro/repositório' | \
    tar -C '/caminho/onde/fazer/deploy' -xf -
```

Na verdade, se o repositório git para o qual você está enviando for "normal" (com uma árvore de trabalho, ao contrario de "bare"), ele fará um checkout automático da nova versão do seu branch apenas se o HEAD dele apontar para o branch que está sendo atualizado.

De forma mais geral, é sempre melhor fazer um push para um repositório "bare" sem nenhuma árvore de trabalho e usar comandos git como `git archive` para extrair dados em algum outro lugar.
Caso contrário, você pode ter conflitos se o repositório de destino não estiver limpo no momento do push.